# Firefox - how to show a standard Downloads popup instead of redirecting to "about:downloads" tab?

Tags: firefox

Well, it's really surprising me that I can't google anything on this problem, but what makes the new version of my Firefox to change its old behavior after clicking Tools --> Downloads? Now, it redirects me to "about:downloads" tab, but I just want to see a standard Downloads popup window! What's going on? How to control this behavior?
Version is 37.0.1

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: About Firefox --> 37.0.1

Comment: I cant see any **Tools** in menu?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "menu". Press Alt. Go to View --> Toolbars, check Menu Bar. This is a standard browser top-level menu - File, Edit, View, History, Bookmarks, **Tools**, Help...

Comment: Does CTRL + J take you to the downloads screen or about:downloads. @Rogue, in FireFox, click the ALT key to see the tools menu

Comment: Would appear you have an issue with the `places.sqlite` database. Try this plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/places-maintenance/

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that about:downloads tab, again. Really buggy, irritating behavior: my download list is not long, but the browser just freezes for a minute before even showing this tab! What happened to that good old popup???

Comment: @Dave @l Iyrically I got that. It does get me the pop-up, not **about:downloads**.

Comment: @lyricallywicked, it *is* still there - just not on your machine, something is corrupted. See my updated comment above

Comment: @lyricallywicked,do you have many plug ins? I would suspect something is conflicting but, a quick re-installation of the browser will probably fix it

Comment: @Dave, I think if the problem is due to plug-ins, it is worth checking with plug-ins disabled and see what happens rather than reinstalling once.

Comment: @RogUE, one would hope that disabling the plugin in Firefox is the same as uninstalling, sadly, it isn't and I have been caught by this numerous times... I agree with you, testing with them disabled first is probably a good decision but for some reason disabling and uninstalling are not the same thing!

Comment: By the way, when I unpack a portable version of Firefox and start the app, it keeps that old behavior showing that popup. But when I open a new page in a Private Window, that "about:downloads" goes on the scene! Well, I'm not sure the problem is in a machine or sqlite... Plugins? Not many. By the way, I have Multiple Tabs Handler...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with FireFox per-se, more about a combination of FireFox and a plugin, or a corruption some where. You don't state what version of Firefox, but I have the latest (37.0.2) and I don't see the issue you describe.

I think you have a few options

1. System restore to remove any changes you've made
2. Try it in safe mode (In browser -> Help -> Restart with add-ons disabled)
3. Uninstall (disable is not the same thing) all plugins in Firefox to try and find the culprit
4. Re-install FireFox

Some have reported good use with this FireFox extension, which examines your places.sqlite (as well as possibly other things) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/places-maintenance/

Comment: I wonder what's the internals that are the **reason** of this. I thought there might be a special option for such a behavior (maybe in "about:config")!

Comment: I added a version number in a question.

Comment: We can't answer that, we don't work at Mozilla :)

Comment: Well, you're not on the latest version  :D

Comment: Still wonder why no preference for this, in "about:config"

Comment: "go to about:config, and do a search for 'download'" - of course, I did that before asking this question here. Found nothing that may be related to the problem, in there...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this has nothing to do with a specific firefox version or a plugin.
I guess the reason is that you start your new version (maybe even the portable one?) in "**permanent private browsing mode**".

The about:config toggle is: *browser.privatebrowsing.autostart* or navigate to

```
Options -> 
Privacy & Security -> 
History -> 
  "Firefox will 'Never remember History'" 
  or 
  "Use custom settings for history" -> "always use private browsing mode".
```

When this mode is enabled, CTRL+J and the *(Show all) Downloads* Buttons will open about:download instead of the popup.

I can't tell you why this different behavior exists - but it sure is confusing. Its those little bad UI/UX things that slowly might ruin a software. Still ❤ FF though.